# Can I serialize data to send to a Infragistics isgrid using json instead of sending a IQueryable<T> object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, infragistics

I'm using an Infragistics isGrid defined below. Is there anyway I can get it to work with a json string instead of an IQueryable object?

```
function bindSitesGrid() {
try {
$("#TheftGrid").igGrid({

}
]
});

var parameters = $('#VTRModifiedCriteriaForm').serialize();
var url = '/VTR/VehicleTheftRecovery/Search/?ticks=' + new Date() + "&" + parameters;

$('#TheftGrid').igGrid('option', 'dataSource', url);
}
catch (error) {
console.log(error)
}

}
```

So can I do this

```
Public Function Search(ssViewModel As VehicleTheftRecoveryVM) As ActionResult


Return View(Json(siteSearchResults))
End Function
```

Instead of this

```
Public Function Search(ssViewModel As VehicleTheftRecoveryVM) As ActionResult


Return View(siteSearchResults.AsQueryable())
End Function
```

Comment: What about `Return Json(siteSearchResults)`?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work hence my question.

Comment: Well what does "didn't work" mean, we need you to be explicit or we cannot help.